# Overlaying image background over sliding page elements

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

Hey there,

I have dynamic question marks on my landing page that scroll with you as you scroll down the page (see @rayku.com/start). I'd like to make it so that these question marks and corresponding scrolling content are hidden behind the brick background that I have on the same page.

I tried using z-indexes but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas?

Thanks! To see the page in action, please visit http://rayku.com/start and scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `position:relative` to your `whiteboard` div : `style="z-index:100000000000000;position: relative;"`

Comment: The idea is correct, but your z-index will overflow the maximums set in browsers, which might lead to unexpected behaviour. Consult this table for maximums in different browsers: http://www.puidokas.com/max-z-index/ (Also note, that reference is from 2009, so things may have since changed.)

Comment: @nikc the value for z-index is taken from the code of the actual page in question. I have used to to make it clear where the position setting should go.

Comment: Even so, I thought it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

The dom element having the brick background, and the question mark elements should be a direct sibling to each other. After arranging in this way. Try giving either position "absolute or relative" to both the brick background element and the question mark element.
After this try giving a greater z-index for the brick element than the question mark element.

Thanks